# How to get an element with varying namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I wish to get the element name of the below xml.
My issue in my request is that I want to get the Payload element. For that I used this expression

```
name(//env:Payload)
```

So I am getting this result **env:Payload**

```
<env:requeset xmlns:env="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope" xmlns:ggg="http://fai.dgn.sss/ggg">
<env:clientbody>
<env:Payload>
<ggg:Service>
<ggg:Request>
<a>name</a>
<b>age</b>
<c>address</c>
</ggg:Request>
</ggg:Service>
</env:Payload>
</env:clientbody>
</env:requeset>
```

But some times my client sends requests with different elements and some times without namespace as well. So how would I get the below request also

```
<requeset xmlns:="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope" xmlns:ggg="http://fai.dgn.sss/ggg">
<clientbody>
<Payload>
<ggg:Service>
<ggg:Request>
<a>name</a>
<b>age</b>
<c>address</c>
</ggg:Request>
</ggg:Service>
</Payload>
</clientbody>
</requeset>
```

For above request I am using same expression so its giving errors so how would I get the Payload element in 2 cases or  any case.
I have tried with this but its not working

```
name(//( local-name()='Payload'))
```

Its giving `ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.`

So please guide to get that element without namespace and different namespaces also I have tried with Contains expression also but I am unable to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, the syntax you wrote is incorrect. If you want to compare the local name of each element, you can do like this:

```
//*(local-name() = 'Payload')
```

But wait, there are better options out there to achieve that. What you are doing here is basically disregarding the namespace. You can also use the wildcard namespace operator `*` to achieve this with a much clearer syntax. It is as simple as

```
//*:Payload
```

If you still want to respect the namespaces you can also merge two results, using the union operator `|`. This way, you get the Payload element with env namespace and without any namespace:

```
//env:Payload | //Payload
```

Of course, in all these cases you can use `name()` to get the element name.

Comment: +1 for showing different approaches - even if I do not agree that `*:Payload` has a clearer syntax than using `local-name()`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller well, maybe that's a matter of taste. However, it definitely is shorter. Also, for many processors the namespace wildcard notation will be faster, at is it easier to optimize.

Comment: But some time namespace is not defined like without prefix that time //*:Payload will not work giving error of prefix so how would i get element name with prefix without prefix and namespaces will vary.again //*(local-name() = 'Payload') this is giving same error

Comment: @user3595078 You are wrong, `//*:Payload` will give you Payload with and without a namespace. Also, the other expression is definitely valid XPath. You might be calling it wrong. Which processor do you use and how do you call the XPath execution?

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood your data and your problem; in consequence, you are asking a question irrelevant to your situation.

You do not have any elements with varying namespaces.  Both the requests you show have elements whose expanded name is {http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope}Payload; they differ only in using different prefixes (`env` vs no prefix at all) for that namespace.  The same query should work fine for both; a simple demonstration is:

```
declare namespace e = "http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope";

let $testdata := <data>
  <env:requeset xmlns:env="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope" 
                xmlns:ggg="http://fai.dgn.sss/ggg">
    <env:clientbody>
      <env:Payload>
        ...
      </env:Payload>
    </env:clientbody>
  </env:requeset>
  <requeset xmlns="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope"
            xmlns:ggg="http://fai.dgn.sss/ggg">
    <clientbody>
      <Payload>
        ...
      </Payload>
    </clientbody>
  </requeset>
</data>

return $testdata//e:Payload
```

If you try this, you'll see that it returns two elements, not just one.

If you are having problems with the second of your sample inputs, it may be because the string `xmlns:` is not a legal name for a namespace declaration.  Change `xmlns:="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope"` to `xmlns="http://eai.ssss.xxx/Envelope"`.