# How to sort the Data in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb.
I wish to transform the data using wso2esb i have done the issue is while response i am getting data in descending manner how would i arrange in to ascending way .

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
       </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <open:employeeresponse xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
         <env:enve xmlns:env="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope">
            <Domain xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">mnh</Domain>
            <Service xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">customer</Service>
            <Sender xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">amng</Sender>
            <MessageId xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">7001274870</MessageId>
            <Language xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">En</Language>
            <UserId xmlns="http://eai.mc.rt/Envelope" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">kmt</UserId>
            <env:Payload>
               <customer xmlns="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer" xmlns:ns2="http://www.openuri.org/">
                  <Response>
                     <Result_OutputData>
                        <resultCode>0</resultCode>
                        <reference_ID>23455</reference_ID>
                     </Result_OutputData>
                     <Output>
                        <mmount_No>1</mmount_No>
                        <mmount_Type>Business Individual</mmount_Type>
                        <Company_Name>AKA</Company_Name>
                        <codeid>556</codeid>
                        <Current_Status>AC</Current_Status>
                        <Status_Desc>ACTIVE</Status_Desc>
                        <Enhance_Data/>
                        <Enhance_Data_Fax/>
                        <Tariff_Plan_Code>GSM DIW</Tariff_Plan_Code>
                        <Tariff_Plan_Name>FARSI MOBILE DETAILS</Tariff_Plan_Name>
                        <COW_Date>2013-10-22+05:30</COW_Date>
                        <PUK1>12345678</PUK1>
                        <PUK2>2</PUK2>
                        <hj>0</hj>
                       </Output>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>255</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>0</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>10</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>0</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>true</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>9</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>8</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>0</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>true</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>7</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>200</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>6</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>100</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>5</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>4</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>3</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>2</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                     <mm:Output_Data xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer">
                        <mm:empid>1</mm:empid>
                        <mm:amt>1000</mm:amt>
                        <mm:date>Wed Sep 30 20:20:30 IST 2009</mm:date>
                        <mm:/>
                        <mm:Flag>false</mm:Flag>
                     </mm:Output_Data>
                               </Response>
               </customer>
            </env:Payload>
         </env:enve>
      </open:employeeresponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I wish to arrange the **mm:Output_Data** tag data in ascending order based on **mm:empid** so how would i arrange this I tried with xquery but i couldn't find the any function regarding element sorting , cusId should be appear  in 1,2,3,... 
I have tried with this XSLT
but no erros and no expected response

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mm="http://eai.rtk.rt/customer" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"></xsl:strip-space>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//mm:Response">
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//mm:Result_OutputData" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//mm:Output"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//mm:Output_Data">
               <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="//mm:empid" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

but its not working not giving any results.
How would i achieve this i know there is no function in xpath for this
thanks in advance.

Comment: Before asking new questions, _accept_ the answers that were given for your past questions (for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25465718/1987598) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25276601/1987598)). Accepting questions is considered good manners on SO.

Comment: Thanx for replay XSLT is not working in wso2esb .Thats whay i didn'taccept the same

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off, but the issue is mainly around this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//acc:Output_Data">
```

Firstly, the namespace prefix **acc** is not defined in your XSLT, which is an error. From looking at the XML though, you should be using the existing **mm** prefix.

Secondly, by beginning the xpath expression with `/` then this makes it a absolute expression, starting from the top-level document node. By using `//` you will select all `Output_Data` anyway in the document. A similar issue exists for the sort expression.

In short, your statement needs to look like this, to make to use the correct namespace, and make it relative to the node you are currently positioned on.

```
       <xsl:apply-templates select="mm:Output_Data">
          <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="mm:empid" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
```